# How to decrypt an RSA-encrypted message if I know p, q, dp, and dq?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I have the values of *p*, *q*, *dp* (which is d (mod p - 1)), and *dq* (which is d(mod q - 1)), and of course, the encrypted message itself.

I don't understand how to extract the remaining necessary values to decrypt the message.

In addition, the numeric values are so huge almost no online calculator site can solve them. (The encrypted message is 308 digits, *p* and *q* are each 155 digits, and *dp* and *dq* are each 154 digits, and the *n* value I got from multiplying *p* and *q* is 309 digits.)

If I were to write a program to solve it, C# or Python would be preferred.

I am very new to learning encryption and decryption, so a walkthrough perhaps in the answer would be very much appreciated!

Comment: too broad, *and* a duplicate of   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240391/rsa-find-d-q-p-from-e-n-dp#comment73555628_43240391

Comment: @JamesKPolk I don't know e. And why is it too broad?

Comment: Ok, not a duplicate, just too broad.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Why is it too broad? I don't know encryption that well. Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The RSA math is explained in [RFC 3447, section 5.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-5.1.2), you want Step 2, part b.  And then you'll need to unpad the message, either according to OAEP or PKCS1 rules (see section 7).